# Scripting SQLite database creation

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm generating Schema.sql file and I want programatically to create sqllite db file and execute all sql statements from file.

thanks

Comment: So far I was manually created db file with manually imported sql statements and now I want to move further and execute those programatically. So, I need some link examples, some site which point me to the right direction.

Comment: maybe this helps, Scripting SQLite database creation,  http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Scripting_SQLite_database_creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SchemaExport class to generate the scripts, and/or apply them to the database : http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.html

```
public class GenerateSchema_Fixture
{
    [Test]
    public void Can_generate_schema()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (Product).Assembly);

        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true /*script*/, true /*export to db*/,
                 false /*just drop*/, true /*format schema*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I already have generated Schema.sql, I'm struggle with how to execute those sql from the file into db. Thanks

Comment: ok, where should I find created sql db file. My schema.sql is generated inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0, but db file is not there. Tried in bin and obj\Debug but again nothing

Comment: It will be the SQLite db file specified in nhibernate connection string